# How do I confirm that HC3 has fixed Heteroscedasticity?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, breusch-pagan

My data is heteroscedastic and cannot be remedied with transformations (I tried boxcox to no avail). I've recently found out about HC3 but am unsure about its effectiveness, as I've run a breusch-pagan test after using HC3 and it returns the same p-value (<.05) as my pre-HC3 model...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: HC3 is a type of heteroskedasticity consistent (aka robust) standard error. Look it up. It won’t affect your BP-test but short answer is that you don’t have to care about heteroskedasticity if you use robust SEs

Comment: Also, unfortunately, you can’t confirm that it worked. But it does, in theory at least